# How to add email validation to below code?

Tags: reactjs

The below code is using cards to show account creation, deposit and other module.

I need to refractor the code to add email, name, and password field validation, but I am not able to do it.

context.js

```
const Route       = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link        = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
const HashRouter  = ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter;
const UserContext = React.createContext(null);

function Card(props){

    function classes(){
      const bg  = props.bgcolor ? ' bg-' + props.bgcolor : ' ';
      const txt = props.txtcolor ? ' text-' + props.txtcolor: ' text-white';
      return 'card mb-3 ' + bg + txt;
    }
  
    return (
      <div className={classes()} style={{maxWidth: "18rem"}}>
        <div className="card-header">{props.header}</div>
        <div className="card-body">
          {props.title && (<h5 className="card-title">{props.title}</h5>)}
          {props.text && (<p className="card-text">{props.text}</p>)}
          {props.body}
          {props.status && (<div id='createStatus'>{props.status}</div>)}
        </div>  
      </div>      
    );    
}
  
function CardForm(props) {
    const ctx = React.useContext(UserContext);  

    return (
      <>
      <div style={{maxWidth: "18rem"}}>
      <div className="name-field" style={{display: props.showName}}>
        Name<br/>
        <input type="input"
          id="txtName"
          className="form-control" 
          placeholder="Enter name" 
          onChange={e => ctx.name=e.currentTarget.value} /><br/>
      </div>

      <div className="email-field" style={{display: props.showEmail}}>
        Email address<br/>
        <input type="input"
          id="txtEmail" 
          className="form-control" 
          placeholder="Enter email" 
          onChange={e => ctx.email=e.currentTarget.value}/><br/>
      </div>

      <div className="password-field" style={{display: props.showPassword}}>
        Password<br/>
        <input type="password"
          id="txtPassword" 
          className="form-control" 
          placeholder="Enter password" 
          onChange={e => ctx.password=e.currentTarget.value}/><br/>
      </div>

      <div className="amount-field" style={{display: props.showAmount}}>
        Amount<br/>
        <input type="number" 
          className="form-control" 
          placeholder="Enter amount" 
          onChange={e => ctx.balance=e.currentTarget.value}/><br/>
      </div>
      </div>
      </>
    )
}
```

creatAccount.js

```
function CreateAccount(props){
    const [show, setShow]     = React.useState(true);
    const [status, setStatus] = React.useState('');
    const ctx = React.useContext(UserContext); 

    function addUser() {
        ctx.balance = '0';
        fetch(`/account/find/${ctx.email}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.length===0) ctx.user = true;
        })
        .then(() => {
        if (ctx.user===true) {
            const url = `/account/create/${ctx.name}/${ctx.email}/${ctx.password}/${ctx.balance}`;
            (async () => {
                var res = await fetch(url);
                var data = await res.json();
                console.log(data);
            })();
            ctx.user='';
            setShow(false);
        } else {
            ctx.user='';
            setStatus('User already exists with that email');
            setTimeout(() => setStatus(''),3000);
        }})
    }

    return (
        <Card
            bgcolor="primary"
            header="Create Account"
            text=""
            status={status}
            body={
                <>
                {show ? 
                <>
                <CardForm setShow={setShow} showAmount="none"/> 
                {<button type="submit" className="btn btn-light" onClick={addUser}>Create Account</button>}
                </>
                : 
                <Success setShow={setShow}/>}
                </>
            }
        />      
    );
}

function Success(props) {
    return (
        <>    
        <h5>Success!</h5><br/>
        <button type="submit" 
            className="btn btn-light" 
            onClick={() => props.setShow(true)}>Add another account</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

I have tried multiple solutions from online content, but they do not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lets simplify this
**Using NPM package email-validator**

1. Install via NPM

   npm install email-validator
2. `import * as EmailValidator from 'email-validator';`
3. Bind your local state to your input field e.g

   ```
   const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
   const [valid, setIsValid] = useState(false);

    <input
       type="text"
       name="email"
       value={email}
       onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
     />
   ```
4. Create a function to check for email validation like below

   ```
   const validateEmail = (email) => {
      setIsValid(EmailValidator.validate(email));
   };
   ```
5. Now there comes two cases. One is to show the validation on change the input field or check on submitting the whole form. To give the validation message while inputting email, you have to use the **useEffect** hook just like below

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     if (email) {
        validateEmail(email);
     }
   }, [email, validateEmail]);
   ```
6. You can use the **valid** state for validation message while user is entering the email something like below

   ```
   <span>{valid ? 'Email format valid' : 'Invalid email format'} <span>
   ```

**Second Case**
just call the function we created above for email validation and check the valid state.